# sliding Regular Expression Syntax C#

Tags: c#, regex

Given this input: `123456789`
I need a regex that will product a `MatchCollection` with the following `match.Value`s:
`123; 234; 345; 456; 567; 678; 789`

So far, I tried to use "backreference", greedy, grouping, etc, but with no luck.  Obviously i am too dumb to find the solution by myself.

Comment: why regular expression? There are many simpler way to achieve such result

Comment: @Garath It also applies in places with more complex expressions that may not be possible otherwise.

Comment: @Garath, Rawilng is right.  i only simplified the "atomic" regular expression to (\d{3}), to keep it short and enhance focus on the "sliding" behavior.

(details, if you really want them: The actual situation is: i need to identify credit card numbers embedded in a looong string of digits)  Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matches cannot overlap. But you could get those in a [`Group`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.aspx) instead:

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches("123456789", @"(?=(.{3}))."))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

The trick here is the combination of a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Note that the trailing `.` is not really necessary, because the engine will advance the starting position by at least one character anyway, but it makes the intent a bit clearer, I think. Also note, that if your input contains line breaks, you'll want to either omit that trailing `.`, use `[\s\S]` instead or use the `RegexOptions.Singleline`.

Alternatively, you can use the [`Match()` overload that takes an offset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3583dcyh.aspx):

```
Regex r = new Regex(@".{3}");
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    Match m = r.Match(input, i);
    if(m.Success)
        Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

But neither does that give you a `MatchCollection` nor does it justify using regular expressions any more, since you could just as well use [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) now:

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length - 2; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(i, 3));
}
```

Of course, the first two approaches easily generalize to more complex regular expression (while the third one doesn't): In the first one you can replace the contents of the lookahead with an arbitrary regular expression in the second one you can just use an arbitrary expression right away.

Comment: THANKS A LOT!   
I took your first suggestion and only added one closing parenthesis (for closing the foreach), only a teeny tiny correction.   

Then replaced the .{3} by the 'real' regex that would match a credit card number, and verified it was working perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you can do this using [positive lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in conjunction with a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"(?=(\d{3}))");
```

You'll need to look at each match's `.Groups[1].Value`.

Comment: ahhh, beat me to it by 36 seconds ;)

Comment: gr..... I tried to do this in JS `alert('123456789 '.match(/[0-9]{3}/ig))` but it doesnt overlap....

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Uh, that's a completely different regex. Of course it doesn't overlap. You're not using lookahead.

Comment: (i know ,  I thought it will overlap :-))

Comment: @Royi Namir, nope, it will NOT overlap, the regex engine will "consume" three digits, and then will advance on to the 4th digit of the sequence.  That is exactly the behavior i needed to supersede in the first place.  I am sure it makes sense to you ;) ... anyway thanks for paying attention to my Q; and putting your hands on.  appreciated! : )

Answer (score 1):

No need for regex:

```
string str = "123456789";
var threes = Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length - 2)
                       .Select(i => str.Substring(i, 3));
foreach (var item in threes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: please refer to other answers (Rawling for instance.  The atomic regex was hyper-simplified only for readibility.  I dont need to obtain a substring.  The real case NEEDS a regexp.